# Why does "django-bootstrap-v5" exist?

Tags: django, bootstrap-5

I've been following a tutorial "https://youtu.be/0mCZdemSsbs" and others (some Bootstrap 4 others v5), that do not use "django-bootstrap-v5" (see https://django-bootstrap-v5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ).  I'm wondering if / why it exists, and should I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the code it looks like it includes Bootstrap v5 in your django templates
https://github.com/zelenij/django-bootstrap-v5/blob/main/src/bootstrap5/bootstrap.py#L5

Compared to it's predecessor django-bootstrap4 which includes Bootstrap v4 in your django templates
https://github.com/zostera/django-bootstrap4/blob/d546447ba166c9fcb756d9a26d4327044b4d08e6/src/bootstrap4/bootstrap.py#L5

So if you were relying on Bootstrap v5 specific enhancements such as `dropdown-menu-dark` you would want the v5 version.

Comment: I'm not asking BS v4 vs v5, but why I would even use it at all... when I can just add the BS lines to my base.html.  What do I gain (or lose) by using it.  I currently have a BS page working,  but now wondering (newby) if I'm doing things the best (or maybe not quite best) way... and why / why not...

Comment: It looks like both of those packages offer templatetags mainly around rendering django forms using bootstrap... so if you have already implemented a manual solution to do this you may not want the automated solution provided by these packages.